# How to link an html form to a batch file?

Tags: html, batch-file, electron

I have this batch file, which is supposed to run the `npm` package `Nativefier`:

```
SET /P _inputname= Please enter a URL:
nativefier %_inputname%
```

I would like to run this from an electron app's `index.html`. I have previously tried using an html `form` and using the following javascript:

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    WshShell.Run ("Experiment.bat");
  });
```

However, this has not seemed to work. Does anyone have a better solution? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

(I am doing this with the intent of building a desktop application, it is not for a webpage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`ActiveXObject`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Microsoft_Extensions/ActiveXObject) API you're using is only available in old versions of Internet Explorer, and not Chromium (which is the browser engine behind Electron).

In general, in order to run a native executable from Electron, you want to use Node.js [`child_process`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module. It should look something like this. Make sure that `webPreferences.nodeIntegration` is `true` in your BrowserWindow options so that you can use Node APIs in your renderer process.

```js
const { spawn } = require("child_process");
$("form").submit(() => {
    const process = spawn("path/to/executable.bat");
});
```

Note that you don't necessarily need a `.bat` file at all.

If you have `nativefier` as a dependency, you could grab the executable from your `node_modules` folder and spawn that directly. For instance (assuming that your form submission contains the URL required for Nativefier to run:

```js
const { spawn } = require("child_process");
$("form").submit((myURL) => {
    const process = spawn(`/node_modules/path/to/nativefier/binary ${myURL}`);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much!